# Making a UINavigationController go back via code

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

The UINavbarcontroller will go back to the previous VC when i press the Left button on the NavBar. Works as expected.

I also need to force the screen to go back from another button, so was wondering is there something i can call to make this happen? I dnt see any method attached to UINavbarController docs for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try [`popViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/popViewControllerAnimated%3a):

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try looking at the [UINavigationController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) docs instead, it's the fourth of 8 instance methods:

> popViewControllerAnimated:
>
> Pops the top view controller from the navigation stack and updates the
>   display.

```
- (UIViewController *)popViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated
```